# Retrieving friend count delta

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've been looking through the Facebook-graph API for a way to get a kind of 'delta' of friend changes since a given date. it looks like the `/<id>/friends` end point will give me a total count at the current time. What I'd like is that same value but for a historic date (i.e. where the date is this time last year, so that I can see how many friends someone has made/lost since then).

(I was originally hoping Facebook would just let me see when people became friends, but it looks like a user's friends list, and all the related details, are off limits).
Unfortunately I can't just rely on the use of future dates, though that may be the solution I end up with (as in, I request the count at the current date, and then at some point in the future request it again and compare the difference).

I can see from my own Facebook account that they do track when a friend/connection was made, and I'm not looking to dig up details on the friend/connection. Ideally I'm looking for something like `/<id>/friends?asat=<date>`

As a follow up question assuming this feature isn't available through the facebook-graph API, how would I go about requesting this feature for a future version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to get the history, you can only call the API endpoint on a regular basis and store the difference with date on your own.

Feature requests can be sent here: https://www.facebook.com/help/contact/268228883256323

...although, i doubt that they will implement this, to be honest. Those kind of "insights" are usually only available for Pages, but not for User Profiles.